# create video with fluctuated background color and drawbox with fluctuated color?

Tags: ffmpeg

Is there anyway to create a video with fluctuated background color choosing from a list for example `[R, G, B]` the background color along time will be R,G,B,R,G,B .... I might use nullsrc with geq. But seems the geq is quite slow which apply to each pixel.

I would also like to change the color of drawbox too, is there any easy way to do it? I knew we might be able to use openclsrc but it seems overkill for this simple task.

Update, for drawbox I found a way, which is kind of abuse the timeline editing:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i smptebars=r=30:d=30:size=800x600 -vf "drawbox=enable='eq(mod(n,3),0)':x=0:y=0:t=20:c=red,drawbox=enable='eq(mod(n,3),1)':x=0:y=0:t=20:c=green,drawbox=enable='eq(mod(n,3),2)':x=0:y=0:t=20:c=blue" /tmp/test_box.mp4
```

Comment: drawbox isn't animatable - I'll look into it.

Comment: @Gyan Unfortunately yes. But I finally found a work around, please see the update. I wonder if there is any thing smarter to do.